# Acquire Google API to obtain real-time road accident/incident feed

Tags: google-maps

I am currently working on a project to introduce real-time road accident/incident feed on vehicle tracking/managing CAD system. I do see live incident alerts on Google maps such as accidents,construction work, road closures, and other hazards that I would like to add to our CAD system. We already have Google Maps subscription for other software development purposes. I would like to know how accident/incident API could be acquired to add the same feed to existing Google Map platform in our CAD system?